# Angular, electron, typescript and robotjs

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron, robotjs

I'm trying to use Typescript together with Electron and RobotJS.
I'm a beginner with all of these technologies so I lack the deep understanding of what is happening behind the scenes so I cannot really connect the dots on this issue.
Electron and my app are working fine, everything compiles, but RobotJS won't work. The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/robotjs/build/Release/robotjs.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I tried rebuilding RobotJS for Electron but it still doesn't work.
Is this a native node module? I'm not sure, gotta read up on it first to figure out what I have to do with it if it indeed is.

Is this even achievable? 
Thanks and have a lovely day!

LE: It would appear that I was trying to use robotjs that relies on node (main process) from angular (rendered process). When I moved what I was trying to do with robotjs from the angular component to main.ts that is ran by electron, it worked. I will try and find a way to use it from angular, I guess Inter-process Communication or something, since I couldn't find any other way for now. 
Still waiting for ideas since I'm kind of in the dark right now.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed along the [robotjs electron documentation](http://robotjs.io/docs/electron)?

Comment: Yup, did this  "rebuild": "npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=4.0.2 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --abi=64" and it it still gives that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured this out. 
Basically you cannot access Electron's Node.js API straight from Angular.
For that you need an awesome tool called `ngx-electron`. Read about it [here](https://thorsten-hans.com/integrating-angular-and-electron-using-ngx-electron-9c36affca25e) or just Google it.
After you install this tool you can just DI its service as most guides instruct you and then use Electron `remote` to get access to `robotjs`.
Basically this:

```
const robot = this._electronService.remote.require('robotjs');
// The example supplied by robotjs
robot.setMouseDelay(2);

const twoPI = Math.PI * 2.0;
const screenSize = robot.getScreenSize();
const height = (screenSize.height / 2) - 10;
const width = screenSize.width;

for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  const y = height * Math.sin((twoPI * x) / width) + height;
  robot.moveMouse(x, y);
}
```

Might not be the best solution but with my current limited knowledge about these technologies this will have to do. 
I'm open to opinions tho.

Thanks for your time, have a nice one!